# fractional power on $(-1)$, e.g., $(-1)^{5/2}$ and $(-1)^{7/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How should I find the value of $(-1)^{5/2}$ and $(-1)^{7/3}$ ?
Thanks !

Comment: This is studied in basic complex analysis - I am afraid that this is too much of a textbook/Wikipedia question even for math community.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know from your mathematics classes, the equation $X^2=-1$ does not have a solution as a "real" number, because all real numbers square to positive numbers.

That's why several centuries ago, people invented "complex" numbers, which are numbers of the form $a+bi$ where $i^2=-1$.

Now you *can* answer your question:
$(-1)^{5/2} = \sqrt{(-1)^5}=\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$.

And $(-1)^{7/3}=\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{3})\pm i\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{3})$ because $(\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{3})\pm i\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{3}))^3=(-1)^7$ (See also [Eulers formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) )

Note how, similarly to $\sqrt{4}=\pm 2$ (because $2^2=4$ but also $(-2)^2=4$), we have a "choice" to take $(-1)^{5/2}=i$ or $(-1)^{5/2}=-i$. For positive numbers, we have chosen $\sqrt{4}$ to be the value $>0$, so $\sqrt4=2$. However, when we go complex, this choice is not as clear-cut anymore. We could say $\sqrt{-1}=i$ and then obtain $i=\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{(-1)^3}=(-1)^{3/2}=\sqrt{-1}^3=i^3=-i$, which clearly is problematic. Therefore, when switching to complex numbers, we are very careful about fixing this choice and working with non-integer exponents.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain a little more (all the steps) about $(-1)^{7/3}$?   
The line is not clear to me. Thank you again.

Comment: The correct steps for $(-1)^{7/3}$ is saying $-1=e^{\pm\pi i}$ so $\mathrm{Log}(-1)=\pm\pi i$, and then using $(-1)^{7/3}=e^{\frac73\mathrm{Log}(-1)}=e^{\frac{\pm7\pi i}3}$ and then using Euler formula $e^{a+bi}=e^a(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))$ to get $e^{\frac{\pm7\pi i}3}=\cos(\pm\frac{7\pi}3)+i\sin(\pm\frac{7\pi}3)$. Then using $\cos(\pm x)=\cos(x)$ and $\sin(\pm x)=\pm\sin(x)$ and periodicity of $2\pi$ gives $(-1)^{7/3}=\cos(\frac\pi3)+i\sin(\frac\pi3)$.

Comment: thank you so much :)